# Delete row data from one table using check box and insert the deleted row data in another table

Tags: php

/*I have two table , 1st table name is bazar and 2nd table name is bazarduepayment having same columne name : sl,date,item,paid,due,remark. 'sl' is auto increment . Delete function is working perfectly . Someone please help me how to insert deleted row data in 2nd table 'bazarduepayment' Here below is code detail i wrote */

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("rwdbconnection.php");
error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {
   $checkbox = $_POST['check'];
   for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
    {
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 
    mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM bazar WHERE sl='".$del_id."'");
    $message = "Data deleted successfully !";

   }
   }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM bazar");
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <linkrel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Delete data</title>
 </head>
  <body>

   <div>
   <?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
   </div>

   <form method="post" action="">
   <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAl"> Select All</th>
   <th>Sl</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Paid</th>
   <th>Due</th>
   <th>Remark</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <?php
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row["sl"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["sl"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["item"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["paid"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["due"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["remark"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
        }
        ?>
        </table>
        <p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="save">DELETE</button></p>
        </form>
        <script>
        $("#checkAl").click(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! there is no data to copy after you deleted data already. So does it make sense to you to copy it BEFORE delete operation?

Comment: Deleting permanently may cause some issues in the future.In practice what we are doing is editing status column in table, instead of delete whole record. (Just change status as 0, set default value of status as 1)

Comment: NEVER silence all error reporting with `error_reporting(0);`

Answer (score -1):

First you need to copy the data from one table to another using `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax and only then you can delete.

You should be using prepared statements for this.

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    // Prepared INSERT query
    $stmt_insert = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO bazarduepayment(date,item,paid,due,remark) 
        SELECT date,item,paid,due,remark FROM bazar WHERE sl=?');

    // Prepare DELETE query
    $stmt_delete = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM bazar WHERE sl=?');

    // Loop on all checkboxes selected
    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $del_id) {
        $stmt_insert->bind_param('s', $del_id);
        $stmt_insert->execute();

        $stmt_delete->bind_param('s', $del_id);
        $stmt_delete->execute();
    }
}
```

You could even simplify this to get rid of the `foreach` loop entirely.